# Is it inefficient to access a python class member container in a loop statement?

Tags: python, performance, language-features

I'm trying to adopt some best practices to keep my python code efficient. I've heard that accessing a member variable inside of a loop can incur a dictionary lookup for every iteration of the loop, so I cache these in local variables to use inside the loop.

My question is about the loop statement itself... if I have the following class:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self)
       self.myList = [ 'a','b','c', 'd', 'e' ]
```

Does the following code in a member function incur one, or one-per-loop-iteration (5) dictionary lookups?

```
for letter in self.myList:
     print letter
```

IE, should I adopt the following pattern, if I am concerned about efficiency...

```
localList = self.myList
for letter in localList:
    print letter
```

or is that actually LESS efficient due to the local variable assign?

Note, I am aware that early optimization is a dangerous pitfall if I'm concerned about the overall efficiency of code development.  Here I am specifically asking about the efficiency of the code, not the coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An iterator is created from `self.myList`, and that iterator is used. No other extra lookups are done on `self` for the iteration.